# How to make dynamic variables with less in a CSS file?

Tags: css, less, css-variables

Actually I want to use a CSS variable in less...

```
:root {
    --header: #6B66A4;
}

@header: #6B66A4;
```

How?

Comment: `@header: var(--header);` ? Remember, though: Less variables are evaluated at *build time*, CSS custom properties are evaluated at *runtime*.

Comment: you cannot .....

Comment: https://developersink.com/css/css-custom-properties-sass-variables/

Comment: @connexo I want less file put the exact "var(--color)" in parameters... Is there any thing?

Comment: @TemaniAfif there must be something!!!

Comment: @moh3n.jj no, this is not how CSS variables works. Use less variable then put less variable inside CSS one, not the opposite

Comment: Check my answer, I think it does exactly what you are asking for. Less can obviously **not** replace `@header` with `#6B66A4` in the generated CSS - also it cannot use something like `darken(@header, 10%)` for the same reason. That is what the browser will do dynamically.

Comment: You still haven't explained what is not working for you. Also, you have not at all properly explained **what you need**.

Answer (score 0):

Less compiles the following

```
:root {
  --header: #6B66A4;
}

@header: var(--header);

body {
  color: @header;
}
```

to this CSS being generated at **build time**:

```css
:root {
  --header: #6B66A4;
}

body {
  color: var(--header);
}
```

Of course Less doesn't know anything about what `var(--header)` means or is - it's just a `string` to Less.

Comment: It is, check https://www.beautifyconverter.com/less-compiler.php. Also, what exactly do you mean by *not working* - without specifying that, your comment is worthless.